# Count documents in Mongo aggregate result?

Tags: mongodb

I have the following aggregate:

```
var duplicatesCursor = db.users.aggregate({
    $group: {
        _id: "$model.email",
        count: {$sum: 1}
    }
}, {
    $match: {
        _id: {$ne: null},
        count:{$gt:1}
    }
});
```

How do I could how many matches it finds? I assumed something like:

```
print("Found duplicate emails: " + duplicatesCursor.length); // undefined
```

Comment: Use `.toArray()`? Count the documents in an iterating loop? The shell returns a "cursor", and this type of cursor does not have a `.count()` property, nor can you use `.length` until converting to an actual array with `.toArray()`. Depends on how large the actual results are as to which approach is best. You could always add `{ "$group": { "_id": null, "count": { "$sum": 1 } }}` to the end if you were **only** interested in the count. Quite a few possible interpretations.

Comment: Thanks. I never thought of this :)